# JPA sequence for serial number

Tags: java, jpa

I wonder is there a clean (or native) way to generate sequence for a table, to use it as a serial number. It needs to be consecutive (1, 2, 3 ...etc), and avoid any possible race/transaction issues(if multiple user try to persist same time). It doesn't require to be the primary key.

```
   @Id
    private Long id;

    private Long serialNumber;
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder is there a clean (or native) way to generate sequence for a table, to use it as a serial number.

To my knowledge, no, not for a non `Id` field.

But you could use a dedicated entity with the appropriate generator strategy and persist a new instance when required to get the next id from it.

Another option would be to simulate a TABLE generator strategy and to use native SQL to read the next id from it and increment it.

Comment: I guess the second option is straight forward, provided the transaction is ensured (if many concurrent users try to create the same entity).

Comment: @bsreekanth: Yes, I second this (and this is very likely what I would implement).

Comment: As you commented below, I was looking for a sol for non id field. an example, say we have 2 customers, and need customer_request_id of each customer to be contigous. Eg. Intel_1, Intel_2... ,IBM_1, IBM_2.. .

Comment: @bsreekanth: You can tweak the "TABLE-like" generator strategy to use multiple lines (depending on the customer), concatenate a special key, etc. You can make this as flexible as you want.

Answer (score 1):

@id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY) ?

Comment: The OP is looking for a solution for a non `Id` field.

Answer (score 1):

DataNucleus supports use of @GeneratedValue on non Id fields.

Comment: thank you..that is a neat feature..  unfortunately, I use a hibernate based system.

Answer (score 0):

@SequenceGenerator

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey#Using_Sequence_Objects

Comment: The OP is looking for a solution for a non `Id` field.